# Is there a "revert" or "restore" function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, default

Say I make a function that on-click changes div color,
is there a function that on another click, restores the div to it's default or previous color, before the change?
(without having to specify what was the previous color)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .toggleClass() to add/remove a CSS class, and specify the color in your CSS.

Comment: +1 This is the optimal solution. Styles should be defined in CSS. There are of course exceptions but 99% (or even more) should reside in CSS file. Toggling classes is simple and fast compared to checking current styles and saving them.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, although I trust there are ways around this. Easiest one that comes to mind would be to either add and remove a class specifies a color OR add the color with `.css('color','red')` say and then remove the style attribute `.removeAttr('style')`.

The latter would only work if you aren't adding with multiple styles and only wanting to remove one. The former would work in this case provide you are happy to set up a class for each style combination/possibility.

Personally I always try to use classes to change visual aspects of webpages so that would be my preference